# Is it possible to change the way a blackberry organizes email after enterprise activation?

Tags: bes

We recently rolled out a Blackberry Enterprise Server.  In the past, everyone had their blackberry connected to the enterprise email through their provider's Blackberry Internet Server.

Quite a few people are now cranky that all their enterprise email goes to the same "mailbox" as their missed calls and SMS messages and such.  They want to go back to the old way of having a separate icon on their phone that *only* has enterprise email messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the inbox, click the blackberry button and select options. Then select General options. Then scroll down to "SMS and Email Inboxes" and set it to seperate. This will split the Email from SMS.

Missed calls will go to the email inbox though. To stop that go to the call log and click the BB button again and select options. Then go to Call Logging and set it to never. You will still get the missed call icon and it will show in the call log, but it won't be displayed in the message inbox.

Comment: Thanks!  That pretty much exactly solved the problem as well as I care to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way, without third party software, to fully seperate BES and BIS email.

I know there is a third party product called [Empower](http://www.getempower.com/Empower_BES_MailBox.php) that seperates the two.  Each user would have to purchase and install it though.

Another workaround is as follows: (got this off of Blackberryforums)

> -At the home screen, open Messages.
>
> -Press options (the button with all of the dots to the left of the
>   trackball).
>
> -Scroll down and select Search
>
> -Scroll down and change service to your BIS account, leave everything
>   else blank/default.
>
> -choose menu > save.
>
> -Set the title to something (ex. BIS Mail)
>
> -then choose a shortcut letter (this will be the shortcut key)
>
> -Save your settings.
>
> When you return to the messages
>   folder, you can filter out your BES
>   messages by pressing ALT and the
>   shortcut key you assigned earlier.
>
> You can then do the same thing for your BES account aswell.